# How to test Rails devise login with token auth in a RESTful API with RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I built a RESTful API using Ruby on Rails and am now at the point of only letting authenticated users make requests. Therefore I implemented an ApiController:

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken
  before_action :authenticate_api_v1_user!
end
```

I use a React client that sends the required auth headers with every request. It all works well so far. Only that I have problems simulating the login in my request specs.

In theory, I would create a user and log them in. But how do I send the token along with the request?

```
describe 'Items API', type: :request do
  # initialize test data
  let!(:user) { create(:user) }
  let!(:items) { create_list(:item, 10) }

  # Test suite for GET /api/v1/items
  describe 'GET /api/v1/items' do
    # make HTTP get request before each example
    before { get '/api/v1/items' }

    it 'returns items' do
      expect(json).not_to be_empty
      expect(json.size).to eq(10)
    end

    it 'returns status code 200' do
      expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
    end
  end

  ...

end
```

The crucial part of the request is the request cookie:

```
authHeaders {
  "access-token":"sMKTl2Zx_8S5f12ydhSaPw",
  "token-type":"Bearer",
  "client":"rzarzdBXCv2SsS9XvYMLVA",
  "expiry":"1546427742",
  "uid":"104006675969015609263"
}
```

It is sent along with the request.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, but one work around could be to sign in user and then add auth token to the header params.

```
Module AuthSpecHelper
  def auth_spec_request(user)
    request.headers.merge!(user.create_new_auth_token) if sign_in(user)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this on the Devise Wiki: [How To: sign in and out a user in Request type specs (specs tagged with type: :request)](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-sign-in-and-out-a-user-in-Request-type-specs-(specs-tagged-with-type:-:request))

> ...but a simpler approach is to just:
>
> **spec/rails_helper.rb**
>
> ```
> RSpec.configure do |config|
>   # ...
>   config.include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers, type: :request
> end
> ```
>
> And just use `sign_in` in your request spec.
>
> This is the equivalent of declaring `include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers` in an system/feature spec or Rails system/controller test.

Answer (score 0):

You can add headers to the `get` request, like so:

```
get 'path', params: {...}, headers: {...}
```

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Integration/RequestHelpers.html#method-i-get

Comment: I actually need to send a request cookie along. I clarified that in my question.